# Sys is undefined .net 4.0

Tags: asp.net

I know it is missing the ScriptResource.axd but how do i add this handler in .net 4.0?

thanks

Comment: A bit more of your code and context would be a big help in identifying your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem when you try to call the sys before its defined.

2 ways for solve, ether make **the sys call after the ScriptManager tag**, ether call the sys functions **after the page load and Dom is ready** by using the onload from body, or if you use jQuery the [ready() function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx).

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
```